# Django form, dynamic number of fields based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The following is my Django model for different type of questions:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    QUESTION_TYPES = [
        ('SBA', 'Single Best Answer (MCQ)'),
        ('EMQ', 'Extended Matching (Matching)'),
        ('SAQ', 'Short Answer Question'),
    ]
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)

class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.TextField(default="Option")

class Subquestion(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subquestion = models.TextField(default="subquestion")
```

I need a form to create new questions with all relevant fields. The fields needed on the form are dynamically decided based on a field in Question model. If question type if SBA is chosen, there should be 5 options fields (no subquestions) appearing and saving to the related models. If EMQ is chosen there should be 5 subquestions, and 7 options fields appearing. if SAQ is chosen no subquestions and options should appear.
I tried using formsets but due to poorly written tutorials I could not understand. As the changes in question type should instantly change the remaining field, I am interesting in dynamic form fields. Any one can help?

Comment: To me it looks like a case for polymorphism. Make three separate views or templates, in the GET view before rendering check which type of question is it and choose corresponding template for rendering.

Comment: Django is the back-end of your application. If you don't use a front-end framework additionally, your only way to interact with django is when reloading, or loading a site. Therefore the task "question type should instantly change the remaining field" is without utilizing e.g. javascript almost impossible. I can show you how to implement dynamic choices but this (for this case) requires following flow: a) select question type, b) load site with correct number of options c) then enter the options and again d) submit and load site.

Comment: Does that mean Django formset cann't be put into use for this scenario?